# Android emulators not showing correctly on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

On a Windows 10 machine, I'm trying to use emulators for Android development but run into the problem that the emulators do not show any characters:

[image]

This happens for all emulator types. The one showing in the screenshot is a Pixel 2 device. I have performed a reinstall of the video drivers, the emulator part of the Android SDK and the HAXM driver, but no success so far.

Are there more persons encountering this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just found the cause of the problem:

[image]

Setting both options in this emulator settings screen to 'autodetect' & 'autoselect', and restarting the emulator solved the issue.